# Get response data from node API using MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to get data from my database table using Node JS API with MySQL, but I am unable to get it. I get the data in console but not returned to the API.

My code is -

```
const config = require('../../../config/config');
var con = config.con;

module.exports = (app) => {

  app.get('/api/counters', (req, res, next) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM counters", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      .then((counter) => result.json())
      .catch((err) => next(err));
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the data from the database you should remove the `then` and `catch` function within the function. ie:

```
app.get('/api/counters', (req, res, next) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM counters", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var counters= result.recordset;
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes I checked after removing the catch and then, but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions but at last i found this and it works for me and i get my response correctly.

```
app.get('/api/counters', (req, res, next) => {
 con.query("SELECT * FROM counters", function (err, result, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  return res.json(result);
 });
});
```

By the way thanks for helping me out of that.